# is firebase ideal for a music streaming app. (Flutter)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

Almost eveything is done through the database, and so this got me thinking, if I have user accounts, is there a way to create/allow certain things from the database,to be user configurable. For example, say they favorited a song, though it is done through the server, it'll be user base and only affect them.

Is there a way to allow certain things from the main database to be user database as well.

Sorta new to this.

Comment: Hi Derived Pierre-Louis, I'd suggest looking at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask first, so that someone here can help you better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely use firebase for music streaming ,

1. for  basic upload you can use firebase storage, and use the download link to stream using [Audio Players plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers)
2. if you want to compress audios to different qualities you can use [Firebase Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) by adding your own javascript to it.
3. The rest is just data manipulation and user management. You can refer the firebase documentations for more.

Comment: Note that the audioplayers plugin appears to have major issues with playing on iOS that don't seem to make sense. audioplayers plugin fails to play `audio/mpeg` files, only if those files have a length longer than 10-12 seconds, so its really only useful for very short audio files